# How to return string by matching two values with similar characters?

Tags: javascript

Not much helpful question title. Let me explain: For a search functionality, I use the code below to return items that match a search query:

```
filter(value: string, query: string): boolean {
      return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
   }

filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(i => this.filter(i.value, this.queryString));
   }
```

I have a case where I need to return an item whose value is **DIGER** if query string's value, containing Turkish characters, is **DİĞER** and vice versa.

I tried

```
if(query.includes('ğ') || query.includes('ş') || query.includes('ö') || query.includes('ü') || query.includes('ı') || query.includes('ç')) {
     return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.replace('ğ', 'g').replace('ş', 's').replace('ö', 'o').replace('ü', 'u').replace('ı', 'i').replace('ç', 'c').toLowerCase()) > -1;
 }
```

Not working quite as I demand, it only converts the Turkish characters, but I couldn't find any solution. How would I accomplish such a task?

Comment: So, what else do you want to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that `value.toLowerCase()` may still include Turkish, so if the new `query` is searching for English characters only, it may not be found inside the new `value`.

One option would be to use an *unconditional* conversion of both the `value` and the `query` to English characters, after which you can use `includes` to check if the new `value` (the haystack) `.includes` the `query` (needle):

```
const chars = {
  ğ: 'g',
  ş: 's',
  ö: 'o',
  ü: 'u',
  ı: 'i',
  ç: 'c',
};
const convert = str => str
  .replace(/[ğşöüıç]/g, char => chars[char])
  .toLowerCase();


filter(value: string, query: string): boolean {
  const [replacedValue, replacedQuery] = [value, query].map(convert);
  return replacedValue.includes(replacedQuery);
}
```

Comment: To make it work correctly with all cases(for example it didn't find 'YAZIŞMA' when 'yazisma' was searched. I put the **toLowerCase()** method before replacing the characters. But it solved my problem, accepting this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@CertainPerformance 's answer is not correct for all situations. There is a official valid way to solve this problem. String.toLocalLowerCase() method;

```
function filter(value: string, query: string): boolean {
    return value.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')
        .indexOf(query.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR')) > -1;
   }
```

---

```
// ------- Test Code ----------
console.log(filter('Şaban', 'şa'));  //true
console.log(filter('çoban', 'ço'));  //true
console.log(filter('ağa', 'aĞa'));   //true
console.log(filter('Ömer', 'Öm'));   //true
console.log(filter('Işıl', 'ıŞIl'));  //true
console.log(filter('Ümit', 'ümİt'));  //true
```

If you don't provide 'tr-TR' argument it automatically look browsers language settings but sometimes it gives wrong results when it is converting 'I' to 'ı'.